# Application cache disappear when offline

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have created my service worker with workbox, and it is precaching successful.  However, when I go offline, the application cache disappear and it just won't work.  I am sure my script is loaded in the top directory of my site. Did I missed anything?

Comment: It is impossible to answer you without more information :-) You need to provide the Service Worker script at minimun.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the reason for my issue.  If you are debugging with Chrome, make sure you uncheck "Update on reload" when you check "offline", or else your service worker won't work!